# Why does VirtualAlloc() require flProtect = PAGE_NOACCESS when flAllocationType = MEM_RESERVE?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management

The following call to `VirtualAlloc()` returns an error `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` on x64:

```
LPVOID lp = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 0x10000000000, MEM_RESERVE, 0);
```

That is, I have to use `PAGE_NOACCESS` as `VirtualAlloc`'s last argument. But when I look at the definition of `PAGE_NOACCESS` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx), I find:

> Disables all access to the committed region of pages. An attempt to
>   read from, write to, or execute the committed region results in an
>   access violation.

which has nothing to do with reserving a range of addresses in the process virtual address space.

It seems like the requirement for *flProtect* to be equal to `PAGE_NOACCESS`, when *flAllocationTime* = `MEM_RESERVE`, is simply missing in MS docs. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VirtualAlloc` requires for its last parameter a [memory protection constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx).
None of the memory protection constants are 0, so 0 is not a valid value. This is the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error you are seeing. Therefore, you have to choose at least one of the constants given. One choice is to use `PAGE_NOACCESS`.

I admit, this is not very clear from the documentation, but it is a general fact that you can not assume that `0` is always a valid value for any flag parameter; you always need to check what values you are allowed to give. If `0` is an accepted value then it is listed as such or explicitly mentioned.

Comment: The documentation for this parameter is horrible.  It explicitly tells you that all values on that list are allowed with `MEM_COMMIT`, which by implication suggests that they aren't otherwise allowed.  It tells you what values are allowed with an enclave.  It doesn't give any instruction on what values can be used with `MEM_RESERVE`.

Comment: Yes, it is completely unclear. The only hint comes from the [`VirtualAlloc` explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) with `MEM_RESET`: *"When you specify MEM_RESET, the VirtualAlloc function ignores the value of flProtect. However, you must still set flProtect to a valid protection value, such as PAGE_NOACCESS."*. It's not at all said if `MEM_RESERVE` ignores `flProtect` as well, but it does hint that the function requires a non-zero value for `flProtect` even when unused. The documentation could use some improvement.